# Black screen with just a cursor after updating

Tags: 22.04, login, cursor

After updating and restarting my system the login screen is completely black and just the cursor is visible. I can move my cursor (pointer) and am able to login. When logged in I can see the desktop but barely visible because of strange colored and distorted boxes fill the screen.

I installed a clean Ubuntu without problems but after installing the updates it happens again. When running a terminal using `cntrl, fn alt f3` in my invisible login view i am able to start a normal functioning ui when starting with `startx`.

I this a known problem, i'm not sure where to start looking.

Comment: Looks like a video problem.  What video hardware do you have (Nvidia?...) and what drivers have you installed for it? When running, what driver is in use (nouveau, nvidia, ???)? How did you install the proprietary drivers, if any?